# Function.prototype.bind with null as argument

Tags: javascript

I got quite confused with `Function.prototype.bind()` method.

```
function playsound(raw) {        
}

function onfilechange(then, evt) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        then(e.target.result);
    };
    reader.onerror = function (e) {
        console.error(e);
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(evt.target.files[0]);
}


document.getElementById('file')
  .addEventListener('change', onfilechange.bind(null, playsound), false);
```

Can anyone explain to me what this code fragment does? The `this` is null and second argument is the `playsound` function. I am not quite understanding the usage behind the below line.

```
onfilechange.bind(null, playsound)
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is probably done in order to make code more readable. As you see, `onfilechange` accepts first argument as a callback to be called after `FileReader` loaded, second as `Event` object for retrieving a file.

Without `.bind()` adding an event listener would look like

```
document.getElementById('file')
    .addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        onfilechange(playsound, event);
    }, false);
```

With `.bind()` you get a shorter code, and `playsound` function is prepended to newly created function's arguments list. And `Event` object is appended on event dispatch.

What `.bind()` does is (From [MDN: Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)):

> The bind() method **creates a new function** that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

So when you call it with `onfilechange.bind(null, playsound)`, it creates and returns a **new** function, **always** receiving `playsound` as first argument and using global context (Because `null` is used as context), just like all regular functions use global context, when you call them without `new` operator and not using `.call()` or `apply()` with specific context.

Comment: And Event object is appended on event dispatch means?? How do we get the event object as argument when don't pass.

Comment: When you call `.bind()`, it returns a function, not it's result, so this function can be used in future (On event dispatch in your case). `Event` object is passed by browser.