# React coding need explaination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to understand this code I found from a package [https://github.com/Revln9/react-agenda/blob/master/example/src/agenda/agenda.js][1] because I need to make a Schedule where I can post data into certain days and have it uploaded to a database and retrieved based on user

1 . I was wondering how come the Handle Event functions such as HandleItemchange, HandleItemSize, removeEvent, AddnewEvent, changeview etc... have 2 parameters but only one parameter is used most of the time.

2.Another question is the changeView function set numberOfDays by using the value that is passed into days but when you look at the button class it has 
onClick={this.changeView.bind(null, 7)}>  which passes in a null for days so how does that even work?

3.Would it be plagiarism if I use this package but modify it for my school project? Never implemented a package into a my own project before other then bootstrap.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import { ReactAgenda , ReactAgendaCtrl, guid , getUnique , getLast , getFirst , Modal } from 'react-agenda';

var now = new Date();

require('moment/locale/fr.js');
    var colors= {
      'color-1':"rgba(102, 195, 131 , 1)" ,
      "color-2":"rgba(242, 177, 52, 1)" ,
      "color-3":"rgba(235, 85, 59, 1)" ,
      "color-4":"rgba(70, 159, 213, 1)",
      "color-5":"rgba(170, 59, 123, 1)"
    }


var items = [
  {
   _id            :guid(),
    name          : 'Meeting , dev staff!',
    startDateTime : new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 10, 0),
    endDateTime   : new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 12, 0),
    classes       : 'color-1 color-4'
  },
  {
   _id            :guid(),
    name          : 'Working lunch , Holly',
    startDateTime : new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()+1, 11, 0),
    endDateTime   : new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()+1, 13, 0),
    classes       : 'color-2'
  },
  {
   _id            :guid(),
    name          : 'Conference , plaza',
    startDateTime : new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()+1, 11 , 0),
    endDateTime   : new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()+1, 14 ,30),
    classes       : 'color-4'
  },
  {
   _id            :'event-4',
    name          : 'Customers issues review',
    startDateTime : new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()+2, 10, 0),
    endDateTime   : new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()+2, 15, 0),
    classes       : 'color-3'

  },
  {
    _id           :'event-5',
    name          : 'Group activity',
    startDateTime : new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()+3, 10, 0),
    endDateTime   : new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()+3, 16, 30),
    classes       : 'color-4'
  },
  {
    _id           :'event-6',
    name          : 'Fun Day !',
    startDateTime : new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()+7, 9, 14),
    endDateTime   : new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()+7, 17),
    classes       : 'color-3'
  }
];

export default class Agenda extends Component {
  constructor(props){
  super(props);



this.state = {
  items:[],
  selected:[],
  cellHeight:(60 / 4),
  showModal:false,
  locale:"fr",
  rowsPerHour:4,
  numberOfDays:4,
  startDate: new Date()
}
this.handleRangeSelection = this.handleRangeSelection.bind(this)
this.handleItemEdit = this.handleItemEdit.bind(this)
this.zoomIn = this.zoomIn.bind(this)
this.zoomOut = this.zoomOut.bind(this)
this._openModal = this._openModal.bind(this)
this._closeModal = this._closeModal.bind(this)
this.addNewEvent = this.addNewEvent.bind(this)
this.removeEvent = this.removeEvent.bind(this)
this.editEvent = this.editEvent.bind(this)
this.changeView = this.changeView.bind(this)
this.handleCellSelection = this.handleCellSelection.bind(this)

  }

  componentDidMount(){

    this.setState({items:items})


  }


componentWillReceiveProps(next , last){
  if(next.items){

    this.setState({items:next.items})
  }
}
  handleItemEdit(item, openModal) {

    if(item && openModal === true){
      this.setState({selected:[item] })
      return this._openModal();
    }



  }
  handleCellSelection(item, openModal) {

    if(this.state.selected && this.state.selected[0] === item){
      return  this._openModal();
    }
       this.setState({selected:[item] })

  }

  zoomIn(){
var num = this.state.cellHeight + 15
    this.setState({cellHeight:num})
  }
  zoomOut(){
var num = this.state.cellHeight - 15
    this.setState({cellHeight:num})
  }


  handleDateRangeChange (startDate, endDate) {
      this.setState({startDate:startDate })

  }

  handleRangeSelection (selected) {


this.setState({selected:selected , showCtrl:true})
this._openModal();

}

_openModal(){
  this.setState({showModal:true})
}
_closeModal(e){
  if(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
    this.setState({showModal:false})
}

handleItemChange(items , item){

this.setState({items:items})
}

handleItemSize(items , item){

  this.setState({items:items})

}

removeEvent(items , item){

    this.setState({ items:items});
}

addNewEvent (items , newItems){

  this.setState({showModal:false ,selected:[] , items:items});
  this._closeModal();
}
editEvent (items , item){

  this.setState({showModal:false ,selected:[] , items:items});
  this._closeModal();
}

changeView (days , event ){
this.setState({numberOfDays:days})
}


  render() {

    var AgendaItem = function(props){
      console.log( ' item component props' , props)
      return <div style={{display:'block', position:'absolute' , background:'#FFF'}}>{props.item.name} <button onClick={()=> props.edit(props.item)}>Edit </button></div>
    }
    return (

      <div className="content-expanded ">

        <div className="control-buttons">
          <button  className="button-control" onClick={this.zoomIn}> <i className="zoom-plus-icon"></i> </button>
          <button  className="button-control" onClick={this.zoomOut}> <i className="zoom-minus-icon"></i> </button>
          <button  className="button-control" onClick={this._openModal}> <i className="schedule-icon"></i> </button>
          <button  className="button-control" onClick={this.changeView.bind(null , 7)}> {moment.duration(7, "days").humanize()}  </button>
          <button  className="button-control" onClick={this.changeView.bind(null , 4)}> {moment.duration(4, "days").humanize()}  </button>
          <button  className="button-control" onClick={this.changeView.bind(null , 3)}> {moment.duration(3, "days").humanize()}  </button>
          <button  className="button-control" onClick={this.changeView.bind(null , 1)}> {moment.duration(1, "day").humanize()} </button>
        </div>

        <ReactAgenda
          minDate={new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth()-3)}
          maxDate={new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth()+3)}
          startDate={this.state.startDate}
          startAtTime={10}
          cellHeight={this.state.cellHeight}
          locale="fr"
          items={this.state.items}
          numberOfDays={this.state.numberOfDays}
          headFormat={"ddd DD MMM"}
          rowsPerHour={this.state.rowsPerHour}
          itemColors={colors}
          //itemComponent={AgendaItem}
          view="calendar"
          autoScale={false}
          fixedHeader={true}
          onRangeSelection={this.handleRangeSelection.bind(this)}
          onChangeEvent={this.handleItemChange.bind(this)}
          onChangeDuration={this.handleItemSize.bind(this)}
          onItemEdit={this.handleItemEdit.bind(this)}
          onCellSelect={this.handleCellSelection.bind(this)}
          onItemRemove={this.removeEvent.bind(this)}
          onDateRangeChange={this.handleDateRangeChange.bind(this)} />
        {
          this.state.showModal? <Modal clickOutside={this._closeModal} >
          <div className="modal-content">
             <ReactAgendaCtrl items={this.state.items} itemColors={colors} selectedCells={this.state.selected} Addnew={this.addNewEvent} edit={this.editEvent}  />

          </div>
   </Modal>:''
}


       </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though all these questions are opinion-based i will try to provide you some guidance.

1. Probably just a copypaste or typo, this is just an example, not a 'usage best-practice example'
2. This is not a null days passing, it is just a parameter for context in `bind` function. So basically he is just calling this func with 7 days as parameter. For additional explanation you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27654149/function-prototype-bind-with-null-as-argument)
3. License is MIT, and allows it, so i don't see why you can't. Go ahead!

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You can define as many parameters as you want, but when you don't give them a value they are undefined ([See here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp)). Why they use this here could have many reasons, but I don't see any right know.

**2.** .bind is definded like this: [.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to this line is binding the function to null and gives the parameter of 7 for days.

**3.** Normally not but to be sure look for an license within the project. In your case the license is this:

> The MIT License (MIT)
>
> Copyright (c) 2016
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
>   "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
>   without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
>   distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
>   permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
>   the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
>   EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
>   MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
>   IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
>   CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT,
>   TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
>   SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

found [here](https://github.com/Revln9/react-agenda/blob/master/LICENCE). To be absolute sure you can mention the project within yours.