# Passing null reference into bind

Tags: javascript

This simple code snippet is from [Javascript.info](https://javascript.info/bind)

```
function mul(a, b) {
   console.dir(this); //logs out window object when double is called
   return a*b;
}

let double = mul.bind(null, 2);

alert( double(3) ); // = mul(2, 3) = 6
alert( double(4) ); // = mul(2, 4) = 8
```

The code is followed by this explanation:

*The call to mul.bind(null, 2) creates a new function double that passes calls to mul, **fixing null as the context** and 2 as the first argument. Further arguments are passed “as is”.*

My question is:

We passed null as context(this) in bind, but we can see that context remains as **Window**.
So can I conclude that **null is passed in bind to create copy of the function with preset arguments?**

But isn't it **violating the basic rule of null**? Or is it some hidden use of null which I am not getting ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27654149/5781499

Answer (score 3):

This is intended behavior. [From the MDN link on `bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> if the `thisArg` is `null` or `undefined`, the `this` of the executing scope is treated as the `thisArg` for the new function.

Since you're executing your bind in the global namespace (`window`), the `this` of the bound function will be the global namespace. Also note that this isn't the case in [strict mode](https://javascript.info/strict-mode).