# Is there any difference betwwen these two approaches(bind a function to button with parameter) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Here is the detail:

The first one:

```
someButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  greet('Max'); 
});
```

The second one:

```
someButton.addEventListener('click', greet.bind(null, 'Max'));
```

Comment: check this SO answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27654777/9583747

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's vanishingly unlikely, but it's theoretically possible for there to be a difference in behavior.

In strict mode, `this` doesn't have to be an object. If you do `greet.bind(null`, the `this` will be `null` - and if you do `greet()`, the `this` will be `undefined`.

```js
'use strict';
const someButton = document.querySelector('.btn');
function greet() {
  console.log(this);
}
someButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  greet('Max'); 
});
someButton.addEventListener('click', greet.bind(null, 'Max'));
```

```html
<button class="btn">click</button>
```

But for any even halfway reasonable code, this difference would not be something anyone should be testing - in which case those two approaches are identical for all intents and purposes.

Though, since it looks like `greet` isn't intending to use any `this`, you could consider just not modifying it at all, and just pass it as the handler itself:

```
someButton.addEventListener('click', greet);
```

which I'd consider to be perfectly reasonable (and, importantly, a bit easier to make sense of at a glance).